# programmatically interact with Open File Dialog Box in browser

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to pull elevation data from a website

http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/convert_input

I have successfully figured out how to programmatically click the 'Choose File' Button that brings up an Open File Dialog Box.

```
Private Sub browser_DocumentCompleted() Handles browser.DocumentCompleted
    hDoc = browser.Document
    Dim hInp As HtmlElement = hDoc.GetElementById("uploaded_file_1")

    If hInp IsNot Nothing Then
        hInp.Focus()
        hInp.InvokeMember("Click")
    End If
End Sub
```

Now I am stuck as to how to interact with the pop-up box. I need to fill in the file name of the file that I need to convert and click open from this Dialog box. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am adding the path to the files that I want to upload to a listbox then copying each one to the clipboard and using sendkeys. I am not to thrilled with this method but it works.